# Kubuntu 16.04 command prompt (Alt+F2) and start menu opening only for 1 second

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 16.04, hdmi, thunderbird

I got an issue with my new installation of Kubuntu 16.04. I installed it a few days ago and got everything running, but now I have a strange issue.

Every time I open the start menu or command prompt (Alt+F2) it flickers open, but closes immediately. Strangely this only happens when a window is on the screen.

As soon as there is no window on the current virtual desktop (either minimized or not assigned) then everything works fine. As soon as there is any window opened, it just flickers open for a second.

That happens on all of my virtual desktops (6 in count at this moment) and it started as I was testing something.

All I done was opening links from a Thunderbird RSS feed in Firefox and see the limits of my system. Firefox got stuck for a moment and gave me the "Firefox is already running, but is not responsive message."

Right after that my the issue was visible. I didn't test it a while before, so it could have been something else too.

What I already done is rebooting the system and shutting down, get rid of any stray capacitive load and starting up again.

As I normally use another setup (with XFCE/Enlightment and the like) I don't have another clue what I could try.

Any help on the matter what could cause it is appreciated.

Another thing I noticed is that the 60Hz setting I done for my Monitor was lost too. That is easily visible as the whole thing starts to flicker slightly and as easily fixable as I just have to set it back (over the graphical settings system) to 60Hz.

There is only one Monitor (actually an Orion TV) connected via HDMI.

Thanks for any help in advance!

PS: I wasn't sure about the tagging. If anything is tagged wrong, please point it out politely.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, so here the answer, if anyone else runs into it.

It is an option I activated myself and forgot about it.

If "Window Behavior" -> "Focus" -> "Focus stealing prevention" is set higher than "Medium" (actually when I can see a change in behavior all in all), then this issue of both menus opening and shortly closing after happens.

Set back to "Medium" or lower and the issue is gone.

I set it because I didn't want Firefox to get the focus every time I hit a link and have to go back to Thunderbird and I doubt that this is normal behavior as it seems both menus need focus and close as they don't get it.

Anyway, I hope this helps people doing the same thing and are clueless as I were.